# mod_rewrite configuration fails to route to the PHP file that runs Zend Expressive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mezzio

I am trying to set up Zend Expressive and following this tutorial:
https://zend-expressive.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/using-a-base-path/

It appears to me that my mod_rewrite directives are not being honored.
How can I ensure that Apache honors directives in my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: 1. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog 2. https://haydenjames.io/disable-htaccess-apache-performance/

Comment: I have apache2.4, which uses different logging.  Namely looks like `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`.  Also it says I have to put it into VirtualHost and not into `.htaccess`.  Going to try this out.

Comment: sadly the logging directive does not appear to show anything in my `error.log` file.  Also, copying directives from `.htaccess` file into my `VirtualHost` directive and restarting apache also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to Apache configuration file and restarting apache service seems to be making it work:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```